# Animating column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create a bar chart, and trying to figure out how to animate the changes that I am making to the chart.  I have set animated to true, but its not showing any changes, just redrawing the bar to the new height.

How can I have it animate changes?  Right now I am setting the data with series.setData(), not sure if there is a way to set a specific bar, maybe this is why it does not animate?

http://jsfiddle.net/nycynik/FACtf/

```
var series = this.series[0];

chartData1[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)] = Math.random()*125;
series.setData(chartData1, true);
```

Comment: It's old, but I think that answer your question.http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13548&p=59520&hilit=setData+animation

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer, but Strange!  "Animation is available on chart.addSeries and series.addPoint however, because in these cases we animate from zero and from the existing data respectively." Why not be able to modify a point in a bar chart (or any point for that matter) and have it animate the change in that point?  I don't yet get it.  but the two methods offered, just append more points, not modify an existing.  Ill keep searching, but thanks @RicardoLohmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series.setData() doesn't animate because all the points are thrown away and replaced with new ones.

What you are looking for is [Point.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update%28%29). When you run point update you are only updating the value, so the point is able to animate from the old value to the new one.

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update(Math.random());
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/point-update-column/).

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else arriving here to find this answer should know, that the update function takes a second parameter for animated.  So chart.series[0].data[0].update(Math.random(),true);  will force the animation.  Thanks!